# `send_tweet': undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, twitter

I've been looking for the answer to my problem forever. For some reason I get this error: `send_tweet': undefined method`update' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)'
whenever I try to run my ruby script. I don't know how to fix this. 
Here's the code:

```
class TwitterConnect
    def intialize
        @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
            config.consumer_key = "CONSUMER KEY"
            config.consumer_secret ="CONSUMER SECRET"
            config.access_token = "ACCESS TOKEN"
            config.access_token_secret = "ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
        end
        @client.middleware.insert_after Twitter::Response::RaiseError,   CustomMiddleware

    end

    def send_tweet (twitterMessage = "Hello world!")
        @client.update("New TwitterConnect object intialized")
        puts twitterMessage
    end
end
```

Comment: btw, your error just means there is no method called `update` for the object `@client`. Maybe you need to use some other method? Maybe try `@client.instance_methods` on the object to see what all it has to offer

Comment: It says 'undefined method: instance methods'. I guess that means that @client can't be an instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code you have, your send_tweet method isn't working because @client is never defined. You'll need to fix a couple things to make it work.

First, to have any access, you'll need to create a new instance of the class.

```
tc = TwitterConnect.new
```

Then, you'll be able to access your client instance variable within your newly created TwitterConnect object.

```
tc.send_tweet
```

If, alternatively, you are already doing this step and still getting the error, the problem is likely in the authentication of your config variables within the initialize method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: According to you then, the problem is with the authentication. I've created a TwitterConnect object and called the 'send_tweet' function. How can I fix it so authentication is works.